# memory access error when reading PT_DYNAMIC entries of a Elf32 on Android 6.0

Tags: android, c, elf, dynamic-linking, relocation

To hook a libc function of an Android app (i.e. `app_process32`), I first read entire address space saved in `/proc/self/maps` and for each loaded ELF, I overwrite the matching relocation entry.

Reading a line of `/proc/self/maps`:

```
Elf32_Addr start, end;
sscanf(line, "%8x-%8x", &start, &end);
```

Then I check if it's an ELF by checking the magic. If it's ELF, I read it's PT_DYNAMIC segment and loop through its entries:

```
Elf32_Ehdr *ehdr = (Elf32_Ehdr *) start;
Elf32_Phdr *phdr = (Elf32_Phdr *) ((unsigned char *) ehdr + ehdr->e_phoff);
Elf32_Half phnum = ehdr->e_phnum;
Elf32_Addr dynamic = 0;    

for (; phnum > 0; --phnum, ++phdr) {
    if (phdr->p_type == PT_DYNAMIC) {
        dynamic = start + phdr->p_vaddr;
        break;
    }
}
```

And here's how I iterate dynamic entries:

```
Elf32_Dyn *dyn;
for (dyn = (Elf32_Dyn *) dynamic; dyn->d_tag; dyn++) {
    Elf32_Addr addr = dyn->d_un.d_ptr;
    Elf32_Sword val = dyn->d_un.d_val;

    switch (dyn->d_tag) {
        // rest of the code.
    }
}
```

For some shared objects it's fine however for a few ones I get a SIGSEGV on checkig for-loop condition `dyn->d_tag`. Why does PT_DYNAMIC point to a location which I can't read? Also I noticed that `dynamic` is usually `> end`, is it okay?

I'm using a device running a 32 bit Android 6.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This calculation:

```
dynamic = start + phdr->p_vaddr;
```

is only correct for ELF images that are linked at address 0, which is typical for shared libraries and position-independent executables, but is not required.

I am guessing that you have some shared libraries that have been prelinked to non-0 address.

This library was not prelinked:

```
readelf -Wl foo.so | egrep 'LOAD|DYNAMIC'
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x000684 0x000684 R E 0x200000
  LOAD           0x000e40 0x0000000000200e40 0x0000000000200e40 0x0001e0 0x0001e8 RW  0x200000
  DYNAMIC        0x000e50 0x0000000000200e50 0x0000000000200e50 0x000190 0x000190 RW  0x8
```

Same library after `prelink -r 0x120000 foo.so`:

```
readelf -Wl foo.so | egrep 'LOAD|DYNAMIC'
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000012000000 0x0000000012000000 0x000684 0x000684 R E 0x200000
  LOAD           0x000e40 0x0000000012200e40 0x0000000012200e40 0x0001e0 0x0001e8 RW  0x200000
  DYNAMIC        0x000e50 0x0000000012200e50 0x0000000012200e50 0x000190 0x000190 RW  0x8
```

If the prelinked library is loaded into your application at the prelinked-at address (`start==0x12200000`), you'll end up with `dynamic == 0x12200e50+0x12200000` which is obviously bogus.

To account for this, you need:

```
dynamic = start + phdr->p_vaddr - first_pt_load->p_vaddr;
```

where `first_pt_load` is the lowest `PT_LOAD` segment (which would have `.p_vaddr == 0` for non-prelinked library, and `0x12000000` for the prelinked one).